# Django: ForeignKey linking 2 tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

In these lines of code, under the Bugs table, there's a line of code that reads

`Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

There are a total of 2 tables, the first one is the Project table, and the 2nd one is the Bugs table. How do I edit this line of code and make it in such a way that only the people who's names are mentioned in the Project table appears?

I've tried this but how do I write all the related names and make sure all the names mentioned in the first table are shown on this table?

```
 Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                          related_name= ' ' | ' ' | ' ' )
```

Clearly, using `'' | ''` does not work.

All suggestions will be appreciated.

Also, for some reason, the lines of code I wrote for inline are not being displayed.` Suggestions for this issue will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
       ('Technician', 'Technician'),
       ('Tester', 'Tester')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
   )
   Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Project_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Admin_Name_users+')
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_1_users+')
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_1_users+')
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_3_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Tester_1_users+')
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fieldsets = (
           (None, {
               'fields': ('Project_Name','Project_Description','Admin_Name','Admin_Mail_ID','Project_Manager_1','Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID',
'Technician_1','Technician_1_Mail_ID','Tester_1','Tester_1_Mail_ID','Status_of_the_project','Created','Finish_Date','Supporting_Documents',
)
           }),
           ('Add More Users', {
               'classes': ('collapse',),
               'fields': ('Project_Manager_2','Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID','Technician_2','Technician_2_Mail_ID',
                          'Technician_3','Technician_3_Mail_ID','Additional_User_1','Additional_User_1_Type',
                          'Additional_User_1_Mail_ID','Additional_User_2','Additional_User_2_Type','Additional_User_2_Mail_ID',
                          'Additional_User_3','Additional_User_3_Type','Additional_User_3_Mail_ID'),
           }),
       )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project_Name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "List Of Projects"

class Bug(models.Model):

   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
       ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Tested', 'tested'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Bug', 'Bug'),
       ('Issue', 'Issue'),
       ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
       ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   Project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Issue_Title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Situation_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Basic_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Detailed_Description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
   Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Assigned_to_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reporters_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Deadline_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents_By_Reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Project_Managers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Project_Manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Technicians_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Testers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return '{} ({})  [{}]'.format(self.Project, self.Situation_Type, self.Status, self.Issue_Title)


   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
       if self.id:
           user=self.Assigned_to
           self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID=user.email
       send_mail(self.Admin_Mail_ID, ass=self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID)
       super(Bug, self).save()

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Projects Tasks/Issues"




def send_mail(admin,ass):
    email=EmailMessage('Changes made to Task','Changes have been made to one of your Task reports and we hereby request you to have a look at it at the earliest.', to=[admin,ass])
    email.send()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things that would greatly help you:

- Utilize [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) within your code. For instance, your field names
  should be all lowercase, as in my example code below.
- Learn about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should **almost never**
  see numbered fields (IE: Additional_User_1, Additional_User_2,
  Additional_User_3) in a database. Ideally, these should be moved to a
  separate model.
- Not sure why you are using STATUS_CHOICE and STATUS_CHOICE_1 all over the place. Name these appropriately to what they actually are.
- Your seem to be a bit confused about your verbose names. Please take a look at how I used the names in my example code below. If you have any questions, please let me know.

I have made the assumptions that each Project has only one admin and that each Person only holds on role (for instance, if a person is a Technician, s/he is only ever a Technician). If these assumptions are incorrect, you may have to adjust the code below.

In my example below, I created a Person model with a OneToOne relationship to User for the various people associated with a project. There is a ManyToMany relationship with Project (IE: Each person can belong to multiple projects, and each project can have multiple people). Last, assigned_to on the Bug model is a ForeignKey to Person (multiple bugs can be assigned to one person).

To add more people to a project, just use fieldsets.

This is just a start. I would add additional models for things like Comments and Documents so that you can have more than one comment or document from the project managers, for instance.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
    )
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    supporting_documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'fields': ('project_name','project_description','status_of_the_project','created','finish_date','supporting_documents',)
            })
        )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project_Name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Project"
       verbose_name_plural = "Projects"


class Person(models.Model):
    PERSON_TYPE = (
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
        ('Technician', 'Technician'),
        ('Tester', 'Tester')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_person')
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, null=True, related_name='people')
    mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    person_type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=PERSON_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Person"
        verbose_name_plural = "People"


class Bug(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
        ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
        ('Testing', 'Testing'),
        ('Tested', 'tested'),
        ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
    )
    SITUATION_TYPE = (
        ('Bug', 'Bug'),
        ('Issue', 'Issue'),
        ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
        ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
        ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    situation_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SITUATION_TYPE)
    basic_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detailed_description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # assigned_to_mail_ID - this can be pulled from the assigned_to relationship
    # Admin name and ID can be pulled from the project->people relationship
    reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reporters_mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reported_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    supporting_documents_by_reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    project_managers_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_project_manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    technicians_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    testers_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return '{} ({})  [{} {}]'.format(self.project, self.situation_type, self.status, self.issue_title)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if self.id:
           user=self.assigned_to.user
           self.assigned_to.mail_id=user.email
        send_mail(self.project.admin.mail_id, ass=self.assigned_to.mail_id)
        super(Bug, self).save()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Project Task/Issue"
        verbose_name_plural = "Project Tasks/Issues"


def send_mail(admin, ass):
    email=EmailMessage('Changes made to Task','Changes have been made to one of your Task reports and we hereby request you to have a look at it at the earliest.', to=[admin, ass])
    email.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

@FlyingTeller
Try to take reference from the following declaration.
If you want to create foreign key relation, you need to add another field like I did for the field subscribed_channel of ChannelSubscription class with the Channel class field subscribed_channels_list

```
class Channel(models.Model):
  channel_id = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False, primary_key = True)
channel_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
channel_value = models.IntegerField(blank = False)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
  default = timezone.now)
subscribed_channels_list = models.ManyToManyField(
  'self',
  through = 'ChannelSubscription', #related_name = 'subscribed_channels',
  symmetrical = False
)

class Meta:
  db_table = 'channel'
managed = False

class ChannelSubscription(models.Model):
  channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column = 'channel_id', related_name = 'source_channel')
slot = models.ForeignKey(Slot, on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column = 'slot_id')
subscribed_channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column = 'subscribed_channel_id', related_name = 'subscribed_channel')
is_active = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
  default = timezone.now)

class Meta:
  db_table = 'channel_subscription'
managed = False
```